# Is there a way to programmatically access an ArcGIS Pro project's default geodatabase?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

In the ArcGIS Pro workflow, one typically creates a project that is set up with its own file geodatabase.

Is there a way to refer to this geodatabase *generically* in a python script?

I have been poring over Esri's documentation and can't find anything on this.

Essentially, I would like to do something like this:

```
fc_name = "some_name"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
out_fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(*DEFAULT PROJECT FGDB HERE*, fc_name, "POINT", "#", "DISABLED", "ENABLED", sr)
```

How do I simply refer to `*DEFAULT PROJECT FGDB HERE*`?

This would help me write tools where the user would be able to access the output in whatever project template they happen to have active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Use the `defaultGeodatabase` off the project:

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("C:\\PRJS\\project1.aprx")
p.defaultGeodatabase
'C:\\PRJS\\project1.gdb'
```

Alternatively you can make use of ["CURRENT" as input to the ArcGISProject class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject.htm) when running the code from both the Python window and GP Tools (inside ArcGIS Pro itself).

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
p.defaultGeodatabase
'C:\\PRJS\\project1.gdb'
```

[ArcGISProject class help reference](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/arcgisproject-class.htm)

Comment: I understand that, but what if I don't know what the project path is?  Would I have to get the project path name from the `mp` methods and then find `defaultGeodatabase` from that?

Comment: If you don't know the project path (disk location of the `.aprx` file), then you can't create a reference to the project thus you can't get the `defaultGeodatababase`. I'm not understanding something. You need to know where _something_ is to begin this workflow, why dont you know where the `aprx` is?

Comment: Or wait, are you writing this code in the PYTHON WINDOW? Or do you want to run it outside ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: I have multiple users for a script tool I've written.  They work on a SAN with many different network paths and can create projects in various locations.  I will not know what their project paths are.  I simply want to get the file geodatabase associated with the equivalent of ArcMap's "CURRENT" workspace.  Yes, this is a script tool with get/set parameters meant to be run inside of Pro.

Comment: I see. I updated the answer, simply, just use `CURRENT` like you did in ArcMap. It's exactly the same premise.